# Asp.Net Core. Авторизация в SignalR через консольный клиент. Удаление noauth пользователя

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

Как удалить клиента если он не прошел проверку? Есть вот такой мини код, и мне нужно в случае если авторизация не пройдет - удалить пользователя. Как вариант я думал не удалять, а авторизованных кидать в отдельную группу, но это такое себе решение

```
public Task Authorize(string username, string password)
    {
        using (var db = new UserContext())
        {
            var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
            if (user != null)
            {
                return Clients?.Caller.SendAsync("Send", $"Successfully Authorized, {user.UserName}");
            }
            return Clients?.Caller.SendAsync("Send", $"Unsuccessfully Authorized, {username}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: В смысле удалить из базы? Ввел неправильно пароль и регистрируйся заново? Подсказка: ваше условие может выглядеть как `if (db.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == username && u.Password == password)) ...`. А так, просто разорвите соединение с клиентом после отправки сообщения.

Comment: Нет, отключить пользователя нужно. Из базы я могу удалить. После выполнения кода клиент все еще подключен и может получать через Clients.All

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15895716/12888024

Comment: Это наверное не для core, у меня нет такого определения

Comment: но зато вы теперь знаете, что искать

Answer (score 0):

Для отключения используется `Context.Abort();`

```
public Task Authorize(string username, string password)
    {
        using (var db = new UserContext())
        {
            var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
            if (user != null)
            {
                return Clients?.Caller.SendAsync("Send", $"Successfully Authorized, {user.UserName}");
            }
            Context.Abort();
            return Clients?.Caller.SendAsync("Send", $"Unsuccessfully Authorized, {username}");
        }
    }
```